# Redirecting using dup2() and execve()

Tags: c, io-redirection, dup2, execve

I want to write a function void redirect(char *msg) in C that opens a file named "hello.txt" for writing, create a child process via fork(), then use output redirection (via the dup2() function) to redirect the child's standard output to your open file. Then, have the child use execve to call the "/bin/echo" program and give it the message your were passed in order to write to the file.

This is what I am having now:

```
void redirect(char *msg){
    int fd = fopen("hello.txt", 'wb');
    pid_t child = fork();
    if(child == 0){
        dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO);
        execve("/bin/echo", msg, environ);
    }
}
```

and it is not working, I don't know what to pass into dup2 and execve.

Comment: Note that the second argument to `fopen()` should be a string — not a multi-byte [integer character constant](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.4p10) as you have with `'wb'` (use `"wb"`).  You also should print an error message if `execve()` returns. You should probably use just `execv()` since you aren't changing the environment of the child process.

Comment: Even if you used `open()`, you aren't closing enough file descriptors in the child. **Rule of thumb**: If you [`dup2()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup2.html) a file descriptor to standard input or standard output, close the original file descriptor from `open()` as soon as possible. In particular, that means before using any of the [`exec*()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/execvp.html) family of functions.

Answer (score 2):

`fopen` returns value of type `FILE *`, which is not valid UNIX file descriptor. Use `open` for this, check out `man 2 open`.